# Accessibility to an object from a casting reference using a Virtual/Override method

Tags: c#, casting, reference, overriding

Using a reference from a subclass reference, how behave the accessibility for it methods since they are virtuals?

Suppose this example:

```
public class Asset {
    public string name;
    public virtual decimal Liability {get {return 0;} }
}

public class House : Asset {
    public decimal Mortgage;
    public override decimal Liability {get {return Mortgage;} }
}

House mansion = new House {name = "SomeName", Mortgage = 100000};
Asset a = mansion;
print (mansion.Liability);      // 100000
print (a.Liability);            // 100000 (not 0!)
```

I thought that `a.Liability` would show `0` because it is a reference of type `Asset` thinking of it accessibility from the previous cast.

Comment: Once your override overridden value supresses the rest,  since house was initialized and assigned overridden value is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have created a subclass `House` where `Liability` is overwritten in a polymorphic way, even accessing the reference `a` from the point of view of an `Asset` will get down to the subclass because `Liability` is declared `virtual` in the base class and that's the behaviour you typically want (if you want to use polymorphism).

Imagine a `List<Asset>` where each instance is of a different subtype of `Asset`. You dont want to care about the subtypes but you want to "just access" the `Liability` property and always get the right value depending on the concrete instance. That is polymorphism.

If you would have used `new` instead of override in `House.Liability`, you would have got `0` as result. Because `new` would kind of break the inheritence chain. So looking from a reference of `Asset`, you would just see `Asset.Liability` (because everything else "beyond" is hidden due to `new` in the subclass). But would you look from a reference of `House`, you would see `House.Liability`. That is not polymorphism anymore.

Maybe [Polymorphism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx) will clarify that better for you ;-)

Comment: Ok, sow i need to perform my Polymorphism skills! Thanks!

Comment: @MartinianoBergoglio: I (hopefully) improved the answer so it is a little bit better.

Comment: It was a lot better, the List<Asset> was the perfect example so, thanks again.

Comment: @MartinianoBergoglio glad I could help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite normal, and it is even the principle of polymorphism. If you hope the result = 0, you must either remove the virtual I guess this is not your starting intention ,or you must construct the object 'Asset'. As following :

```
 House mansion = new House { name = "SomeName", Mortgage = 100000 };
            Asset a = new Asset { name = "SomeName" };
            Console.WriteLine(mansion.Liability);      // 100000
            Console.WriteLine(a.Liability); //0 OK
```

What you said is true if there are no virtual. the behavior you expected is presented with the following code :

```
public class Asset
{
    public string name;
    public decimal Liability { get { return 0; } }
}

public class House : Asset
{
    public decimal Mortgage;
    public decimal Liability { get { return Mortgage; } }
}

House mansion = new House { name = "SomeName", Mortgage = 100000 };
Asset a = mansion;
Console.WriteLine(mansion.Liability);      // 100000
Console.WriteLine(a.Liability); //0 OK
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With yours and Markus answers i have a clear view now.